# How to respond to late answers that are duplicates of accepted answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers, review-audits

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4604999) answer was flagged recently.

The answer was provided by others 6 months earlier, and the flagged answer appears to be a "me too" answer that adds little or no value.

How should we proceed with these types of answers?

Comment: Downvote, maybe comment, flag if the answer is an exact duplicate of another one (which is not the case in the example you provided).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228162

Comment: The most important thing I'd like to encourage is to read the "duclicate" carefully and make sure the author really means to ask the same with no serious differences in context and that the answer to the old question actually fits the new one.

Comment: Does it really matter whether they're duplicates of the accepted answer, or of other answers?

Comment: @Frédéric, I posted a feature suggestion aimed to reduce the number of duplicate answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270027/encourage-deleting-ones-own-answer-in-favor-of-another-one-in-order-to-reduce-t

Answer (score 28):

Ideally down-votes should really be reserved for incorrect answers, though the down-vote tooltip does just state "this answer is not useful" and in this case the answer isn't really useful so a down-vote would be justified.

Leaving a comment might help, but be nice. Ask if they meant to highlight an aspect that isn't covered by the other answers for example. Clear cases of "me too" answers should be flagged. You should also consider protecting the question, but only if there are several of these.

In cases of clear plagiarism flag it for the moderators to deal with.

However, I would add that you should double check the time stamps on the answers to make sure that you are correct. I've seen lots of flags where the answers were actually only minutes or even seconds apart and therefore added independently.

Comment: I agree that they should not necessarily be downvoted. I've been skipping them because I don't know what to do with them. And I avoid flagging them because I don't want to hammer moderators.

Comment: "Downvotes are reserved for incorrect answers" is not a true statement.  Downvotes are reserved for answers or questions that the community feels are bad.  No rules govern how to downvote.  The community chooses.

Comment: @PWKad It was, perhaps, a bad choice of words. I meant that you shouldn't really downvote an otherwise correct answer just because it's late.

Comment: Now this is one issue that is prevalent on gaming and SO. A new answerer should check whether what he is posting is already stated. Else as Jeff puts it, it is just line noise.

Answer (score 8):

By definition (or, at least, by my definition), 'late answers' appear many minutes (sometimes months, often days) after the original answers.  Granted, you do get near duplicates that are entered within, say, 15 minutes of each other.  These are not always plagiarism; it could be that it took the later person longer to type up the answer. (I will often select half a dozen questions, opening them in tabs, and then answer them.  I know enough to check for new answers etc before going ahead with an answer to a question I opened half an hour ago; not everyone is as familiar with the site, though.)

I will usually leave a comment to the effect that a new answer to a question with other answers, especially an up-voted and accepted answer, needs to be distinctively different from the current answers to be worth adding.

I'm not sure how kosher it is, but (if you have enough reputation), you can down-vote an answer, flag it for deletion, and then cancel the down-vote.  I've never investigated whether cancelling the down-vote cancels the deletion flag; I don't think it does.

Comment: I posted a feature suggestion aimed to reduce the number of duplicate answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270027/encourage-deleting-ones-own-answer-in-favor-of-another-one-in-order-to-reduce-t