# Flag Duplicate Answers on the same Question

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-answers

Often there are questions like this

[What's the meaning of "=>" (an arrow formed from equals & greater than) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-in-javascript)

where people don't really know the answer but search it on Google and post an answer saying something like

> This would be the "arrow function expression" introduced in ECMAScript 6.

Okay, fair enough. But then the answers start pouring in and every new answer says the same thing copied from internet in different words

> This is an arrow function; it is part of the ECMAscript 6 specification, but not part of "normal" JavaScript in use today.

Another one goes like

> That's known as an Arrow Function, part of the ECMA6 Script Proposal...

I do not mean to imply it's not good to copy official descriptions from the internet, but when someone has already answered such a thing with exact answer as yours, why keep posting?

There are four answers to that question that say exactly the same thing in different words. It's not as if those are code-based answers showing different ways of reaching the solution (which isn't duplicate). These answers all say the same thing and are useless, can we cry duplicate on them?

Comment: Most of the answers I'm seeing in your example have some explanation beyond just the part you quote. So without knowing the domain, at least they seem to attempt to add value. Otherwise, I think the best thing you can do is write a better answer, and let it be voted to the top. Or if there's already an answer that's better than the repetitive ones, upvote it.

Comment: i think there should be really a way to put identical answers into a tab-folder (or whatever) ... i have seen this effect more than once and i would aprreciate it when a Admin would put all those answers into one pot! i wish you could simply flag an answer as "duplicate answer" and all those flagged answers would be summarized (or put on a stack) by an admin!

Comment: Meta [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/how-should-we-deal-with-duplicate-answers)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390907/4014959

Answer (score 88, accepted):

While this is not a common issue, I've seen it from time to time. I believe that some answers simply don't provide additional detail to SO. Here is one case:

> Try launching the SDK Manager by double-clicking the executable (in my case found at C:\DownloadPath\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\SDK Manager.exe) rather than launching it from Eclipse !!

<sub>answered Jul 20 at 19:52 - [Missing Google Play Services in SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301016/missing-google-play-services-in-sdk-manager/24854294#24854294)</sub>

> Lauching the SDK manager in your folder (F:\SETUP\laptrinh\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321) instead of run by eclipse
>
> That work for me

<sub>answered Oct 19 at 17:04 - [Missing Google Play Services in SDK Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301016/missing-google-play-services-in-sdk-manager/26453071#26453071)</sub>

In this case and other similar situations, I add a comment with the following information:

> Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since *another user* already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should [vote it up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Where *another user* would be the user name that answered the previous question.

Besides the comment, I flag it as "needs moderator attention" with the message:

> While this is an answer, it's a "copy" of a previous answer (*link to previous answer*). There is no additional value for SO to keep two answers with the same solution.

It would be nice to have a flag for "duplicate answer" though.

Comment: I just ran across this issue in the *Late Answer* review queue. Almost asked a new meta question about it. Luckily I found your solution. Implementing a **Duplicate answer flag** would be great. Any ideas why it isn't implemented until the time of this writing? (I guess because it is a rare case)

Comment: @NoelWidmer I also just ran into this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448588/975624) from the *Late Answer* review queue. It seems that there's nothing strictly preventing a user from posting a subset of information in a more detailed answer for cheap, easy, yet slow upvotes. [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250884/975624) seems a bit more relevant to our cases.

Comment: How would you flag that answer if there is not duplicate answer flag?

Comment: It would be nice if the delete comments list in the review had a preset for this... I very often encounter people basically posting worse-quality versions of answers posted _years_ before the new one.

Comment: I see many duplicate in my reviews, and yes, I do feel we do should have an easier and official way to flag them for deletion, and reinforce that reviewers should look for these during reviews. Otherwise one could flood SO with "valid" duplicate answers and earn rep from that, as many people seem to upvote these duplicate answers for no good reason (maybe because of the Sportsmanship badge ?!?)

Comment: @NoelWidmer it's not too rare. I found one and I don't know what to do.Which flag should I give for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697941/importerror-no-module-named-nltk-corpus-nltk-is-not-a-package-pycharm)?

Answer (score 35):

If you check the timestamps on the answers you'll see that the earliest were all added within a couple of minutes of each other. This clearly shows that the "duplicate" answers are all really different people providing *the* answer to what is apparently a relatively easy question.

This is how Stack Overflow works. The best explanation should float to the top as it gets more votes than the others.

What you should be looking out for is identical (or nearly identical) answers posted weeks, months or even years later. In *those* cases follow the advice in [Luís Cruz's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274825/59303). Also be on the look out for spam hidden in obscure places.

Comment: `The best explanation should float to the top as it gets more votes than the others.` And what if they are effectively identical (like the kind that this question is asking about)? Do they all then “float to the top”? The point to the question is whether they should be culled.

Comment: @Synetech - Ideally one answer will be sufficiently different with *all* the necessary information to float to the top. It seems a bit harsh to remove perfectly correct answers given in good faith.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2024:** This function is to some extend already implemented via the **plagiarism** tag option (not available when writing this post). However it doesn't completely solve the problem.

### Some ideas how to handle duplicate answers

Some duplicate answers may not have been posted intentionally.
These older threads can easily contain many paginated views – I don't blame new contributors to overlook all previous contributions.

### "Canonical" question threads

Posts being around for several years with 1K+ visitors.

Mapping duplicate questions to canonical posts is crucial to maintain a high quality on SO.

It is quite often hard to catch up with all duplicate questions to redirect them to a canonical one.

However, these canonical question posts are particularly prone to "duplicate answer spamming" - which undermines the whole idea of deduplication.

An advisory message may be helpful similar to the "new contributor - be kind" advice (..uhm, which seem to have vanished for some reason)

Something like this:

(with a red background color ... and maybe in Comic sans! ... pardon me won't work on most android/linux devices)

> This post already provides > 10 answers. Before adding a new
> answer, please make sure your post adds new insights to the topic by
> explaining alternative approaches or elaborate on already mentioned methods

#### Improvements for the »How to ask« section

I think this aspect should at least be mentioned in the current help post:
[**"How to answer"**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Something like this:

> Please read all previous answers and ensure your answer provides a new approach or insight to solve the described problem.

#### Prevent "toxic" downvoting

Granted, there is no way to prevent users from feeling offended by having their posts closed.

But a <del>"flag as duplicate answer" option</del> "avoid duplicate answer" message might significantly mitigate this "user discontent" as it can help to remove an answer without saying "this is very low quality". (and also protecting this answer from being downvoted).

#### Bad example

Here's my contribution to the list of bad examples:
[How do I disable the resizable property of a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235142/how-do-i-disable-the-resizable-property-of-a-textarea/)

(... spoiler: the answer is `resize: none`!)

You don't even have to scroll to see the duplicates ...

Comment: "You don't event have to scroll to see the duplicates" I think you chose a bad example. The duplicate was posted in the same minute. It is unlikely that the user saw the previous answer before he posted his own answer. So it would be hard to tell which answer should be closed if we wanted to avoid duplicates. I'd say it is better to leave both and let users upvote whichever might seem slightly better to them.

Comment: @zoran404: I'meant the 45/48 remaining answers that are not adding anything new to the question.

Comment: Well now that I did scroll.. yea, that post has a literal infestation of duplicates