# Question cleanup needed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, clean-up

This question (["Do I cast the result of malloc?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1783163)) has 27 answers currently.

Actually, the count of the essentially different answers are only around 3, the others are duplicates.

Considering its high visit count, I think some deduplication ( = deleting the dupe answers) would be useful, maybe your votes and flags could here help a lot.

After that, maybe a mod lock could be also useful.

Comment: Well, I don't often agree with @peterh, but just how many ways are there to say 'no'?  27 answers is just clutter:(

Comment: Which answers do to want to keep? If it's the first three, I would argue that the deletion is a bit pointless, as people read the page from top to bottom anyway...

Comment: @MartinJames Some says yes (using different arguments), I actually casted it to avoid some warnings, but now I already know, if it shouldn't be, then why not. I think both the "yes" and "no" answers are useful, but they are too many. :-)

Comment: @user000001 You can vote for down and del. At least the low-score, mainly crap on the end could disappear on this way. It can't be decided centrally, the voters will decide.

Comment: @peterh, There are problems with this. If you delete an independently good answer which happens to *reword* a former answer, (a) the deleted answer poster can justifiably complain, (b) the deleted answer can become a review queue test and fool just about everyone, causing more angst, (c) some people might favour one wording to another, there's no objective measure.

Comment: @jpp 1) No, posting essentially the same answer is not allowed and deletable. 2) If you can't vote for del, you can still vote for down. -> The result is that the community decides, what will happen to the answers. Letting that question as it is now... I see that the worst possible option existing.

Comment: `No, posting essentially the same answer is not allowed and deletable.` Can you provide a reference for "not allowed and deletable"? You can find *many* answers stating the opposite. Rewording answers is often.. welcomed.

Comment: @jpp These are not rewordings. Simply the answerers came and explained their opinions - without even checking the other answer for a spot.

Comment: Mod locks are the nuclear option.  A mod lock suggests that there is such an influx of similar answers that a moderator locking the post is the only solution to fix this.  The post is protected and the last answer made was in '17 by someone who wouldn't have had the protection clause apply to them.  What would we possible gain by locking this question?  Is it ***really*** worth the extra mod effort to do that??

Comment: @Makoto *"A mod lock suggests that there is such an influx of similar answers that a moderator locking the post is the only solution to fix this. "* In my opinion, exactly this is happening. Maybe the community closure of the question (for example, as opinion-based, or to stop the answer flood) would be also an useful option.

Comment: [For the general case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266469/flag-duplicate-answers-on-the-same-question). (cc @jpp )

Comment: @user000001 People reading from top to bottom doesn't mean that they won't read the bottom. Especially for somewhat-opinion-based questions. (in particular this one has both "yes" and "no" answer)

Comment: (on an unrelated note: people read the Q&A before the HNQ list doesn't mean that they won't click on a HNQ. And there are many complains about HNQ kills work efficiency)

Comment: @user202729 Everybody knows that starting a post with some popular thing greatly affects the final voting score of any post in a positive direction. One of the saddest thing of the SE that this trick works. :-(

Comment: I initiated another close vote, this time for opinionatedness (check the endless mass of contradicting *opinions*, practically no one was interested for the opinion of the others, they only said that it should be / shouldn't be casted).

Answer (score 12):

I don't see any good reason to "mess" with the answers on that question.

- There is no plagiarism or other breach of the site's terms.
- There is no harm in having a couple different flavors of the same (/similar) answer on a question.

Locking the post would prevent users from voting on it.
Deleting valid, upvoted answers for the sake of "cleaning up" is just something we don't do.

If you disagree with an answer's usefulness, downvote it. That's all you can do.

Comment: Ironically, I'm basically saying the same thing [jpp is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373785/1835379), but worded differently. That's not a bad thing.

Comment: I already did it. The goal of the post is to attract attention of others, to help with their votes.

Comment: "A couple" different flavors, no harm. But at what point is another duplicate answer pointless? At what point do we cross the line from, "Meh, okay, don't mess with it" to "Alright, this is just getting ridiculous"? (I'm not arguing that this question above has hit that point. Just asking, where do we draw the line? It's much like the duplicate question problem, really- When are they no longer useful as duplicates, rewordings, or signposts?)

Comment: @Kendra, How would *you* decide which answers to keep? Vote count can be a poor measure. We sometimes see very good responses much later, and these responses have less time to attract votes. If some answerer down the list has their upvoted answer deleted and complains, what policy would you point to? The issue is SO has no objective process for dealing with this problem.

Answer (score 8):

Here are the main reasons why such answers can be deleted:

- There's plagiarism involved **and** you can convince the mods it's plagiarism. *You* need to provide the evidence. There are no set criteria; if you can't convince the mods a custom flag will be declined.
- The question is old and the new answer is of **very** low quality. In which case, a custom flag may have the desired effect. Rewording an answer does not in itself constitute low quality...
  <sup>Conversely, it may indicate good quality.</sup>

Otherwise, the only tool available to you is the downvote. If you are generous, go to a popular canonical post and look through the bottom 25% of answers, downvote any garbage you find. You can easily spend 20-30 rep (before you reach your vote cap) with such activity.

If you have time, also check out the higher voted answers. The unfortunate truth is bad or duplicate answers sometimes get upvoted on popular posts, by virtue of the fact they are seen by more users, many of whom may not have reviewed and understood the top answers.

Comment: at 175K views the question might qualify for moderator cleanup [as described by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773)

Comment: Beside downvote, I can 1) flag obvious dupes 2) ask for the votes of others in comments 3) ask for help on the meta 4) I don't vote too much down in general (I have around 20% downs of my ups), but if I vote down, I ignore the answer rep loss. The newer answers are only coming and coming, most answerers didn't even read the previous ones, I think it needs a stop.

Comment: 1) `flag obvious dupes`: covered by plagiarism. Same answer with different wording is **not** covered, they are allowed to stand; 2) `ask for the votes of others`: no, each vote is your own choice; 3) `ask for help on meta`: not scalable for specific questions, we will then have a thousand questions with the same issue.

Comment: @gnat, That's new to me. Is there more recent guidance / examples of this happening in practice? Irrespective, there are several Meta posts supporting same answer with different wording.

Comment: @Cerbrus, If you read my post carefully, that's my point. There is no plagiarism or VLQ answers!

Comment: ... I completely missed that. +1

Comment: @Cerbrus No proof for plagiarism, but they are simply dupes.

Comment: Why is that a problem, @peterh?

Comment: @Cerbrus If their quality is low, then yes it is a problem. But it is up to you, how are you voting. Feel free to vote up all the 27 answers (note, if you read all of them, you will see that around 2/3 of them are VLQ crap, despite their scores).

Comment: An answer being a (borderline) duplicate doesn't make it "VLQ". We don't have a "duplicate" flag for answers.

Comment: @Cerbrus I see no reason to discuss anything with you until you don't make it clear: is the content below that post okay in your opinion, or it is not? You are talking about everything - particularly in focus *anything* with what you hope you can somehow attack/criticize me -, but this single 1 bit of information is somehow still missing.

Comment: How is it not clear that I think the answers shouldn't be deleted?

Comment: @Cerbrus as one who relies on SO when I look for answers to my coding questions, multiple answers, and especially when these repeat the same _are_ a problem, these make it harder to find solution (sorting by votes somewhat helps but still). Have to admit though when I use SO I don't care about obscure rules of when it is legitimate to delete and when it isn't, I just want answer to my question to be easy to find and read

Comment: @Cerbrus Ok. The primary concern of the post is to attract attention to the question, because in my opinion there is something there to do. I have no intent and no power to command you to vote to del; you can vote anything, including voting the posts up; however I suspect the majority of the community won't do that. I consider this discussion is meaningless in this sense, if you think the posts are good and useful, even the fifth replay of "cast/don't cast the malloc result", then vote it up. Bikeschedding about what should be done, including many ad hominem flavor, I think it is

Comment: @Cerbrus perfectly contraproductive and yes, it deserves deletion.

Comment: @gnat, I agree with you *in principle*. In practice, the rules are pretty clear right now and we can't remove reworded answers. If anyone feels strongly about it they can raise a discussion thread on redefining the criteria for deletion. Don't be too hopeful as this ground has been covered again and again.

Comment: @jpp We can remove VLQ answers, and also downvoted answers. The lasting value of the majority of the answers in this post is zero. Or negative.