# Flagging Copy/Pasted Answers in Review Queues

Tags: support

Recently, I was presented with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419840/getting-error-of-cannot-get-while-making-an-api-in-express-js/58451504#58451504) while working through the "Late Answers" review queue. Now, although this is not an **exact** copy of another answer, it **is** an amalgamation+rearrangement of texts extracted from a number of the other answers. (It's also a pretty useless answer, IMHO!)

Having recently returned to reviewing after a short (enforced) 'time-off' period, I have made some *real* efforts to improve my reviewing technique, by thoroughly reading various relevant posts on the Stack Exchange Meta site.

During that 'self-training' period, I'm sure I came across an example and/or recommendation for dealing with copy/paste posts - but I can't remember if the best option was to use a 'normal' flag or a custom (moderator) flag (and I can't now find the page again).

It seems clear to me that the poster of this answer deliberately/knowingly did something wrong, even though it is a new user.

What I have done, in this case, is raise a custom flag, with the following comment:

> Not sure what 'normal' flag to use here! This answer seems to be a
>   mish-mash of text copied from two or more of the other answers.

Was this the correct approach? If not, what would the best approach be? (I do appreciate that Moderators are extremely busy, so I really try to avoid using custom flags if there is a feasible alternative.)

Comment: The first thing you could (or should) do is write a comment explaining the issue with the answer (you should do that outside of the queue). That way other persons will understand the issues you saw with the post. Then you can flag it as "very low quality" (in the review queue).

Comment: @Tom - Good idea? Can I retract the current flag and then raise a new one? (I know I can't retract then re-raise the same one!)

Comment: You normally can't retract and then re-flag, but where were some changes when flagging as NAA and then as VLQ, so I'm not sure what the current rule is. You can test it and if it doesn't work, no worries, this meta post brought enough attention to that answer post, that it will be handled anyway.

Comment: @Tom - Yes! I did what you recommended (and it worked). Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @gnat - That's a useful Q/A you've linked but nothing specific there about copy/paste answers. There's one somewhere (unless I was dreaming about it) but I can't find it.

Comment: Well, "Open the answer link in a new tab and scroll up and down from the answer position to see if it's plagiarism (usually from the accepted answer);". from the link matches this situation. If the answer plagiarizes one or more answers shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: @Tom Possibly - though that section was about "good" answers. Still, plagiarism of gibberish is still plagiarism, I guess?

Comment: When someone copies a full answer, then it looks at the first glance like a good answer, hence that section name there. This example here was just badly done, so it doesn't qualify as a "good" answer anymore, but it is still not gibberish. Gibberish would be something like "ajsdhasjkdbgasjkfbaskdja" or "I ate too much, my stomach hurts :'(" (so something that looks like someone rolled their face other the keyboard or is _completely_ unrelated to anything programming related). So I would still says the actions explained there do match this case here as well.

Comment: possibly you were looking for something like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266469/839601) or one of the questions linked to it

Comment: @gnat - There's an answer there that is pretty close, so yeah - close this one! My request for "support" was answered well (and rapidly), so - job done! But I am still concerned about minimizing the use of "Moderator" flags: Mods are very busy folks *(and there seems to be rather fewer of them now than there was a wee while ago)*.

Comment: you can dupe close it yourself [as explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250974/165773) (my own vote has already gone so I can't help here)

Comment: @gnat - Do I get a special badge for doing that? 

Comment: [it's hardly needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773) :) "You discover that one of the answers in duplicate solves your issue

This is the best possible outcome... It occurred once or twice to me and have to admit, it felt… great. Just think of it, you get your answer, what could be better..."