# Reviewing new answers to famous old question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, first-answers

When reviewing the First answers review queue, sometimes it is an answer for a famous old question with gazillions of already well-written solutions/comments. I just came up with an "answer" that SURELY had been written before with more details. How should I flag this?

Comment: The linked duplicate isn't very specific about this particular, common situation.  [Flag duplicate answer on the same questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266469/flag-duplicate-answers-on-the-same-question) provides additional guidance.