# Could be an irrelevant modification of answer be flagged as a plagiarized answer in the same question?

Tags: support, flags, plagiarism

So I've found this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21592733/888472

and following, in the same question, this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64645886/888472

that only makes an irrelevant modification of a `foreach`

Should be flagged this second one as plagiarized of the first one, even when they are in the same question?

Comment: If you think it's similar enough to constitute plagiarism (as they seem to suggest in the comments that it effectively is: *"the main difference is to use foreach instead of friends.ForEach"*) then flag away. Worst case scenario the mod that handles the flag disagrees. 2 answers being on the same question doesn't mean that plagiarism didn't take place (the exception generally being 2 answers posted in quick succession of one another, in which case, they're duplicate answers, but not plagiarism).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing anything that looks copied here; could you clarify what exactly was copied?

Comment: Note that [obvious duplicate answers that are not plagiarized](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266469/208273) can also be flagged (not as plagiarism), but it should be clear that they're actually duplicates (remember that the handling moderator is probably not a subject matter expert in the technology that the answer is about). (for example, these don't look like _obvious_ duplicates, at least without a detailed explanation of why they're the same).

Comment: @RyanM I suspected that, doing some review tools often skip tasks because are from a technology I don't know anything. Maybe is too hard to explain the difference in some cases, so I imagine it depends. In this case is the same answer but with other syntax that doesn't add anything to the case itself. But I understand your point, thanks a lot

Comment: I don't see a case for *plagiarism*. The code in either answer hardly counts for something that's difficult to come up with independently. It's just...bog standard, almost boilerplate code for getting data and updating it. I understand  a complaint that an alternative syntax isn't a useful answer but not that it's somehow *plagiarised*.

Comment: The line `var idList = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};` is very likely copied (the same [in a third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592596/update-multiple-rows-in-entity-framework-from-a-list-of-ids/75100890#75100890)), but it is probably not sufficient evidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general copy-pasting an answer and changing one word (or a noticeably small amount of text) is indeed plagiarism if there are no  attribution and should be flagged accordingly. Whether the version with attribution can be considered answer is up for you as a reader to consider in each individual case. Ideally such answer will include explanation why the change was needed making it acceptable on SO.

In this particular case there is really no plagiarism - iterating through collection of items in C# can indeed be done in different ways but there is very small variation of how you can actually write those - so code will look similar. Author of newer question was trying to make contrast between different iteration methods but realistically failed to highlight that. I personally agree with commenters on that post that there is not much value in that suggestion, but it is a valid suggestion answering the question. I would not vote it up or down, but I can see reasons for both votes (+7/-3 as of 2022 sound about a right split for me).

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexei, and so I consider you a guru in C# this clear a lot my mind! And thanks for your support in whole S.O. about C#