# Is there an 'easy' way to identify duplicate answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

Is there an easy way to identify (exact or near) duplicate answer on a question?

For example, is someone is reviewing in the Late Answers queue it very possible to come across new answers on very old and well-answered question. In such cases, there is the possibility that the user has posted an exact duplicate answer or just a re-phrased one.

The only thing I can think to identify such cases is, to copy the new and all the old answers to my machine, run a diff and if I have a hit to investigate further?

As I am aware there is not a tool to help you to identify duplicate answer inside StackOverflow (e.g. for a duplicate question we have some hint from the system when flagging).

- Is there any third-party external tool (e.g a javascript) than can
  help someone with the diff?
- Is there any methodology that can help someone to ease the process?

**Note:** When I am talking about duplication, I mean duplicates inside the ***same*** question thread and ***not*** across questions.

Answer (score 2):

It should be pretty obvious if the answer contains almost the same text even without a diff-tool. I would assume.

If they maybe have the same message but a different explanation I would not see them as duplicate. Sometimes a different style to explaining the same thing can be helpful for some people.

Also knowledge about the topic on hand is pretty useful to identify duplicate answers. If you don't know whether they are duplicate and just compare them by diff you may miss a small thing which can be important though.

In case you are not sure the **skip** button is also useful.

Comment: `It should be pretty obvious`, I disagree with this: 1) In review queue I can see only the new answer not the old ones, 2) in some questions you may have 2,3 or more pages with answers. These, especially the second, makes it difficult to easily identify the duplicates. Even if I do not use a diff tool, again I need to iterate through all answers and compare.

Comment: @Athafoud It would be nice if you can see the potential duplicate during review. I can agree with you there. But on another note. Why looking for duplicates in the first place? The flags do not contain "duplicate answer". There is no action you should take from what I see. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think that I just should also look the possibility of duplicates. Maybe I am putting too much effort? I do not know! As for the flag, yes I know there is not such a thing (and I think any feature request to add one, was declined), however there is always the downvote and the comment (as all the 'how to handle duplicate answers' questions on meta suggest).

Comment: @Athafoud I would say you put too much effort in there but you can review as thoroughly as you like. As far as I understand downvotes should also be used in the context of the question and this specific answer. Not compared to other answers. But this is also just how I see them. What you do with your votes is completely up to you. I just guess there is a reason why you only see the answer and the question in the review context and not everything.

Comment: Just for reference [How to respond to late answers that are duplicates of accepted answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250883/how-to-respond-to-late-answers-that-are-duplicates-of-accepted-answers)